# SQL query to select data between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two dates, effective date '2023-07-03' to expiry date '2024-03-31'. I want to retrieve record on `getdate()`.

But I am not getting the results from my query:

```
SELECT 
    [ID],
    [Tariff_ID],
    [Effective_Date],
    [Expiry_Date],
    [Category],
    [Cargo_Class],
    [Wt_Min], [Wt_Max],
    [Charges_PKR], [Charges_Per]
FROM 
    [CARGO].[dbo].[Tariff_Handling]  
WHERE
    Effective_Date >= GETDATE() 
    AND Wt_Min <= 4  
    AND Category = 'AFU' 
    AND Cargo_Class = 'GEN' 
    AND Tariff_ID = 1
```

My current date is greater than to effective date and less than to expiry date but I'm getting any results

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi, problem is with your where clause, getdate() >= effective date and similarly the other date.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your query lies in the condition `Effective_Date >= GETDATE()`. This condition is preventing any records from being retrieved because the effective date of the record '2023-07-03' is not greater than or equal to the current date.

```sql
SELECT 
    [ID],
    [Tariff_ID],
    [Effective_Date],
    [Expiry_Date],
    [Category],
    [Cargo_Class],
    [Wt_Min],
    [Wt_Max],
    [Charges_PKR],
    [Charges_Per]
FROM 
    [CARGO].[dbo].[Tariff_Handling]  
WHERE
    Effective_Date <= GETDATE() 
    AND Expiry_Date >= GETDATE()
    AND Wt_Min <= 4  
    AND Category = 'AFU' 
    AND Cargo_Class = 'GEN' 
    AND Tariff_ID = 1
```